# Typescript and Mongoose: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Document'

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my Mongoose model that I use together with TypeScript:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const userSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 50,
    },
    ...
    ...
  }
);

userSchema.method({
  transform() {
    const transformed = {};
    const fields = ["id", "name", "email", "createdAt", "role"];

    fields.forEach((field) => {
      transformed[field] = this[field];
    });
    return transformed;
  },
});

userSchema.statics = {
  roles,
  checkDuplicateEmailError(err: any) {
    if (err.code === 11000) {
      var error = new Error("Email already taken");
      return error;
    }

    return err;
  },
};

export default mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

I use this model in my controller:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import User from "../models/user.model";
import httpStatus from "http-status";

export const register = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const user = new User(req.body);
    const savedUser = await user.save();
    res.status(httpStatus.CREATED);
    res.send(savedUser.transform());
  } catch (error) {
    return next(User.checkDuplicateEmailError(error));
  }
};
```

I get the following errors:

> Property 'transform' does not exist on type 'Document'.

> Property 'checkDuplicateEmailError' does not exist on type 'Model<Document, {}>'.

I tried `export default mongoose.model<any>("User", userSchema);` and I do not get the `transform` error but still the error for `checkDuplicateEmailError`.

Comment: There are quite a few TS errors here.  I'm seeing red underlines on `transformed[field]` and I'm surprised there's no warning on `err.code` given that `err` is `any`.  You need a bunch of annotations, including defining `User` as having a `transform()` method.  I will write you an answer but I have to check the docs for some things because I know much more about TS than I do about mongoose.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You know that `mongoose.model("User", userSchema);` creates a `Model`, but the question is: *a model of what?*

Without any type annotations, the model `User` gets the type `Model<Document, {}>` and the `user` object created from `new User()` gets the type `Document`. So of course you are going to get errors like *"Property 'transform' does not exist on type 'Document'."*

When you added your `<any>` variable, the type for `user` became `any`.  Which actually gives us less information than knowing that `user` is a `Document`.

What we want to do is create a model for specific type of `Document` describing our user.  Instances of the user should have a method `transform()` while the model itself should have the method `checkDuplicateEmailError()`.  We do this by passing generics to the `mongoose.model()` function:

```
export default mongoose.model<UserDocument, UserModel>("User", userSchema);
```

The hard part is figuring out those two types.  Frustratingly, mongoose doesn't automatically apply the fields from your schema as properties of the type, though [there are packages that do this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mongoose).  So we have to write them out as typescript types.

```
interface UserDocument extends Document {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  createdAt: number;
  role: string;
  transform(): Transformed;
}
```

Our `transform` function returns a object with 5 specific properties from the `UserDocument`.  In order to access the names of those properties without having to type them again, I moved the `fields` from inside your `transform` method to be a top-level property.  I used `as const` to keep their types as string literals rather than just `string`.  `(typeof transformFields)[number]` gives us the union of those strings.

```
const transformFields = ["id", "name", "email", "createdAt", "role"] as const;

type Transformed = Pick<UserDocument, (typeof transformFields)[number]>
```

Our `UserModel` is a `Model` of `UserDocument` and it also includes our `checkDuplicateEmailError` function.

```
interface UserModel extends Model<UserDocument> {
  checkDuplicateEmailError(err: any): any;
}
```

We should also add the `UserDocument` generic when we create our `Schema`, so that `this` will have the type `UserDocument` when we access it inside a schema method.

```
const userSchema = new Schema<UserDocument>({
```

I got all sorts of typescript errors trying to implement the `transform()` method including missing index signatures.  We can avoid reinventing the wheel here by using the `pick` method from `lodash`.  I still had problems with the mongoose `methods()` helper function, but it works fine using the direct assignment approach.

```
userSchema.methods.transform = function (): Transformed {
  return pick(this, transformFields);
};
```

You could also use destructuring to avoid the index signature issues.

```
userSchema.methods.transform = function (): Transformed {
  const {id, name, email, createdAt, role} = this;
  return {id, name, email, createdAt, role};
}
```

Within your email check function, I added a `typeof` check to avoid runtime errors from trying to access the property `err.code` if `err` is `undefined`.

```
if ( typeof err === "object" && err.code === 11000) {
```

That should fix all your errors.

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Qmb1PN)

Comment: How to add `, {timestamps : true}` to the Interface like what we do with the Schema?

Comment: I have a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71934042/property-does-not-exist-on-type-modeldocumentany-any-any-t