# Property 'serializeUser' does not exist on type 'UserModel'.ts(2339)

Tags: node.js, typescript, authentication, serialization, passport-local-mongoose

This is my `models/users.ts` file:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
import passportLocalMongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose';

export interface digitalWalletDocument extends mongoose.Document{
    currencyName: string;
    value: number;

}

const digitalWalletSchema = new Schema<digitalWalletDocument>({
    currencyName : {
        type : String
    },
    value : {
        type : Number
    }
});


export interface UserDocument extends mongoose.Document{
    username :  String;
    firstName : String;
    lastName : String;
    email : String;
    telNumber : Number;
    nationalCode : Number;
    admin : Boolean;
    image :  String;
    wallet : Number;
    rate : Number;
    shabaCode :Number;
    cardNumber : Number;
    birthDay : String;
    status : String;
    address : String;
    documnetPath : String;
    description : String;
    purchased : String;
    digitalWallet : digitalWalletDocument;
}

export const userSchema = new Schema<UserDocument>({
    username : {
        type : String,
        sparse : true ,
        unique : true
    },
    firstName : {
        type: String
    },
    lastName : {
        type : String
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        unique : true
    },
    telNumber : {
        type : Number
    },
    nationalCode : {
        type : Number,
        sparse : true,
        unique : true
    },
    admin : {
        type:Boolean,
        default : false
    },
    image : {
        type : String
    },
    wallet: {
        type : Number,
        default : 0
    },
    rate : {
        type : Number,
        default : 0
    },
    shabaCode : {
        type : Number
    },
    cardNumber : {
        type : Number
    },
    birthDay : {
        type : String
    },
    status : {
        type : String
    },
    address : {
        type : String
    },
    documnetPath : {
        type : String
    },
    description : {
        type: String
    },
    purchased : [String],
    digitalWallet : [digitalWalletSchema]
}, {timestamps : true});

export interface UserModel extends mongoose.Model<UserDocument> {};

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose,{usernameField : 'email'});

export default mongoose.model<UserDocument,UserModel>('User' , userSchema);
```

And the following is the `authentication.ts` file that uses the `user.ts` file:

```
import express, {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import passport from 'passport';
import passportLocal from 'passport-local';
const LocalStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;
import passportJWT from 'passport-jwt';
const passportJWTStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;
const ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
import JWT from 'jsonwebtoken';
import User from './models/users';
import config from './config';

export const local = passport.use(new LocalStrategy( User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
    
exports.getToken = (user: any) => {
    return JWT.sign(user, config.secretKey,{ expiresIn : "2d"});
};

const opt = {
    secretOrKey : config.secretKey,
    jwtFromRequest : ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
};


export const jwtAuth = passport.use(new passportJWTStrategy(opt , (payload ,done) => {

    User.findOne({_id : payload._id},(err: any , user: typeof User ) => {
        if(err){
            return done(err,false);
        }
        else if(user){
            return done(null , user);
        }
        else{
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
}));

export const verifyUser = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session : false});

export function verifyAdmin(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    if(req.user.admin){
        return next();
    }
    else{
        let err = new Error('Only Admin can access to this web page or resources!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
}
```

I get the following error messages:

```
Property 'authenticate' does not exist on type 'UserModel'.ts(2339)
Property 'serializeUser' does not exist on type 'UserModel'.ts(2339)
Property 'deserializeUser' does not exist on type 'UserModel'.ts(2339)
```

The sources of errors are these lines:

```
export const local = passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

I don't know what is the problem and how can I fix it?
I tried to search on the internet and find the similar questions and do what the similar questions' answers suggest but none of them worked for me!

`EDIT`: I changed the code as what @Linda suggests in her answer. But a new error arose as following:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(fn: (user: User,
> done: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void): void', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '(user: UserDocument, cb: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(user: User,
> done: (err: any, id?: any) => void) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'user' and 'user' are incompatible.
> Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'UserDocument': username, firstName, lastName, email, and 66 more.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(fn: (req: IncomingMessage, user: User, done: (err:
> any, id?: unknown) => void) => void): void', gave the following error.

The error happens at this line of the code:

```
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
```

On the `authentication.ts` file.

When I delete the parenthesis in front of the `User.serializeUser()` the error disappears but I am not sure if it was the case.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

The fields which are giving you errors are the ones which are added by the `passport-local-mongoose` package.

When you call:

```
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField : 'email'});
```

You are adding these additional fields like `authenticate()` and `serializeUser()` to your model.

Unfortunately the mongoose [type declaration](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/2119e5aa579d16c756f0497b137059b1704c68c2/types/index.d.ts#L913) for `Schema.plugin()` says that it returns the same object type that it started with:

```
/** Registers a plugin for this schema. */
plugin(fn: (schema: Schema<DocType>, opts?: any) => void, opts?: any): this;
```

So your code cannot detect those added properties automatically.

#### Solution

Step 1:

Install `@types/passport-local-mongoose` to load type declarations for the `passport-local-mongoose` package.

```
npm i --save-dev @types/passport-local-mongoose
```

The additional types are added to the `mongoose` namespace, so you can access them using `mongoose.TypeName` the same as you would access the standard mongoose types.

Step 2:

Declare that your `UserModel` interface is a `PassportLocalModel` rather than a plain mongoose `Model`.

```
export interface UserModel extends mongoose.PassportLocalModel<UserDocument> {};
```

You need to keep the generic type arguments that you already have where you call `mongoose.model()` here:

```
export default mongoose.model<UserDocument, UserModel>('User' , userSchema);
```

But now your `User` model will have [the methods](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8037183a1e02288b66d72c983f247c55d18dde5e/types/passport-local-mongoose/index.d.ts#L36) of a `PassportLocalModel`!

---

As a side note, you want to use lowercase `string` and `number` in your TypeScript interfaces.

Comment: Thank you fot your answer. I tried to modify the code as you suggested but a new error arose. Please look at the EDIT part of my question.